# Is it possible to show a variable from java editing a XML activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I have a TextView which I would like to show how the time passes in a game (it depends on the steps followed, not on real time elapsed).

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Time"/> //Editing this line
```

Is there a way that I could set it to show variables from java to string, instead of setting a constant value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by data binding concept in Android. A view model has to be created and associated with the text view as below.

```
<TextView android:text="@{viewmodel.userName}" />
```

Below link in android developer website explains in detail on how to create a view model.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=Cj0KCQiAuP-OBhDqARIsAD4XHpdBptAbmhtZUFWh0EpQhpvNui7pc9_Br-w8xbimKZHpBkC1K9VC6u8aAg-ZEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
String time = "....";
//...
time = "xyz";
TextView time_tv = findViewById(R.id.time_tv);
time_tv.setText(time);
```

Comment: No, I mean if there is a way to program it on XML code not on java

Comment: `No, that's not possible` why would it not be possible ? why can you not use databinding for this ?